# Can GPS transmission time be the same for two different ephemerides?

Tags: gps

I am seeing a RINEX navigation file where I have two different ephemerides for the same satellite at different times. Nothing surprising. The thing is that they both have the same transmission time, which I understand it is derived from the Z-count from the Handover word. Wouldn't the transmission time need to be different?

I'm not totally familiar with the GPS navigation message. Is it possible that a HOW is sent, then a word containing a GPS ephemeris for a particular SV and then a new word containing ephemeris (different IODE) for the same SV sent again? Is it GPS ICD compliant?